# Add pandas column values only when 1 column value is == to another column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, calculated-columns

I'm in a tizzy and any help would be appreciated.  I have a python pd dataframe.  The goal is to get a total number for each year.  For this I have to add the 'freq' of the 'start' column to "freq2" of the "added_year" column ONLY if 'start' matches "added_year".

```
gender  start   freq    added_year  freq2
0   0   1789    89  1790    89
28  0   1790    6   1791    6
31  0   1791    82  1792    82
69  0   1792    4   1793    4
70  0   1793    123 1794    123

the output would be something along the lines of

start    freq      added_year   freq2     total
1790        6            1790      89        95'''

I think I have to do some kind of map/lambda function or a define a function with a series of if statements, but I am confused as to how to do this.
Thank you.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a self merge and then take a sum.

```
df = df[['start','freq']].merge(df[['added_year','freq2']], left_on='start', right_on='added_year')

df['total'] = df['freq']+df['freq2']
```

Output

```
   start  freq  added_year  freq2  total
0   1790     6        1790     89     95
1   1791    82        1791      6     88
2   1792     4        1792     82     86
3   1793   123        1793      4    127
```